# How to install Composer with Ansible?

Tags: software-installation, php, ansible

In Bash I usually install Composer this way:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

I tried to read in the [Ansible Composer module documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/composer_module.html) **just for a hint** on what is the recommended way to install Composer with Ansible but I found none.

I just want to make sure that each time I install Composer it will be installed by the latest installation-command aside from being continuously upgraded by Ansible from my machine via SSH.

How could I do it in a Ansible "`state: latest`" way (as common with Ansible's `apt` module)?

Comment: What’s wrong with having Ansible execute the two commands you provided to install Composer?

Comment: Nothing enough wrong, I can do that with the `command` module but let's assume the unlikely happened and "tomorrow" the command will no longer be stable, how could I ensure I up2date with that command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `get_url` to output `https://getcomposer.org/installer` to a file `composer-setup.php`, ideally in some directory, let's say `/tmp`
2. Use `command` module to run `php /tmp/composer-setup.php ...` step

Or search Ansible Galaxy, and see if anyone else has done it.

Comment: AFAIK the `command` module is for custom code that never changes, very much like plain Bash with the default shell to be combined in Ansible (I actually wrote it on VSCODE offline). I should read about `get_url` as I'm new to Ansible, I never heard of it before, but should this be like a `curl` or `wget` altogether as well and the command would be transcribed in the future (if there'll be such need) by the Ansible community?

Comment: Anyway, I'll check the Ansible Galaxy.

Comment: I think the get_url calls a urllib library in Python, and might fallback to wget or curl

Comment: Sorry man ! One last thing - I just started a very nice question here regarding this, I believe it might be interesting for you to look at anyway ! https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/489630/understanding-the-advantage-of-using-ansible-galaxy-roles

Answer (score 7):

Do

```
ansible-galaxy install geerlingguy.composer
```

This will add [`geerlingguy.composer`](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/composer) to your roles, which you can then add to your playbook.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an other way to do it, everything is explained here: https://www.devopsaurus.com/install-composer-with-ansible/

```yaml
---

- name: Validate Composer checksum
  get_url:
    checksum: "sha384:795f976fe0ebd8b75f26a6dd68f78fd3453ce79f32ecb33e7fd087d39bfeb978342fb73ac986cd4f54edd0dc902601dc"
    dest: /usr/src/
    url: https://getcomposer.org/installer
  become: yes

- name: Download and install Composer
  shell: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
  args:
    chdir: /usr/src/
    creates: /usr/local/bin/composer
    warn: false
  become: yes

- name: Add Composer to global path
  copy: 
    dest: /usr/local/bin/composer
    group: root
    mode: '0755'
    owner: root
    src: /usr/src/composer.phar
    remote_src: yes
  become: yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Since composer is in apt repository you could simply run with:

```yaml
    - name: Install composer
      apt:
        name: composer
        state: latest
```

(With state "latest" as you want)

Comment: Current composer - ver 2 for some years, but in repo only v1...

Answer (score 0):

Read the checksum, store it in a variable, and download the PHAR file to the `/usr/local/bin` directory. The checksum task is optional. However, PHP is required to read the version.

```
---
- name: "Read Checksum"
  shell: curl https://getcomposer.org/download/latest-stable/composer.phar.sha256
  register: composer_checksum

- name: "Download PHAR file"
  ansible.builtin.get_url:
    url: https://getcomposer.org/download/latest-stable/composer.phar
    dest: /usr/local/bin/composer
    force: yes
    checksum: "sha256:{{ composer_checksum.stdout }}"

- name: "Read composer version"
  shell: composer -V
  register: composer_version

- debug:
    var: composer_version.stdout
```

The expected output

> ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
> "composer_version.stdout": "Composer version 2.1.9 2021-10-05 09:47:38" }